# ZF2 - FormRow does not generate value

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I have an amount field in a FieldSet.

```
private function addAmount()
{
    $number = new Number('amount');
    $number->setLabel('Amount');

    // Attributes
    $number->setAttribute('required', TRUE);
    $number->setAttribute('id', 'product-amount');
    $number->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
    $number->setAttribute('min', 1);
    $number->setAttribute('max', 10);
    $number->setAttribute('step', 1);

    // Label attributes
    $number->setLabelAttributes(array(
        'class' => 'control-label'
    ));

    $number->setValue(1);
    $this->add($number);
}
```

I set the value to one, but after generation of the input field using the FormRow, no value is available.

Is there a nice and clean way to set default values in FieldSet or Form and have them displayed in the view?

Thanks.

-- Edit --

In the form I set the Data as suggested.

$this->setData(array('product' => array('amount' => 1)));
$this->bindValues();

Data is available even in the view, however in the view it's not being used in the Phprenderer FormNumber. View looks like this only relevant elements:

```
    <?php
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('product', array('action' => add')));
    $form->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal');

    $form->prepare();
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);

    $product = $form->get('product');
    ?>

    <div class="form-group <?= ($this->formElementErrors($product->get('amount'))) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <?php
    echo $this->formRow($product->get('amount')) . PHP_EOL;
    ?>
    </div>
```

If I set the amount value in the bound object it is displayed correctly. I cannot populate prior to validation. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to build your form then use the Form object's `setData` method to pre-populate the form with data:

```
// Create the form and add the elements
$form = new Form();
$form->add(new Number('amount'));

// Set the default values
$form->setData(array('amount' => 1));

// Render the form
...
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your response, see above edit, I didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've never manually hacked forms like that, I always use a Factory to create them.  Not sure if setup is a factor here, but this works:

**FORM**

```
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Element,
    Zend\Captcha,
    Zend\InputFilter,
    Zend\Form\Element\Text,
    Zend\Form\Form;

class CreditCardForm extends Form
{

    public function init()
    {

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'card-holder-name',
            'type' => Text::class,
            'options' => [
                'label' => _( "Name on Card" ),
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'maxlength' => 64,
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**INPUT FILTER**

```
namespace Application\InputFilter;

use Zend\Filter\StringTrim;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Validator\StringLength;
use Zend\Validator\CreditCard;

class CreditCardInputFilter extends InputFilter
{

    public function init()
    {

        $this->add([
           'name' => 'card-holder-name',
           'required' => true,
           'filters' => [
               ['name' => StringTrim::class],
           ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**FORM FACTORY**

```
namespace Application\Factory\Form;

use Application\Form\CreditCardForm;
use Application\InputFilter\CreditCardInputFilter;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\MutableCreationOptionsInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;

/**
 * Class ServerFormFactory
 */
class CreditCardFormFactory implements FactoryInterface, MutableCreationOptionsInterface
{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options;

     /**
     * Set creation options
     *
     * @param  array $options
     * @return void
     */
    public function setCreationOptions( array $options )
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        /**
         * @var \Zend\Form\FormElementManager       $serviceLocator
         * @var \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager $serviceManager
         */
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        try
        {
            $form      = new CreditCardForm( 'card' );
            $form->setHydrator( new ClassMethods() );
            $form->setInputFilter( $serviceManager->get('InputFilterManager')->get( CreditCardInputFilter::class ) );
        }
        catch( \Exception $x )
        {
            die( $x->getMessage() );
        }


        return $form;
    }
}
```

Glue that together in your config, e.g.:

**CONFIG**

```
'service_manager' => [

    'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            CreditCardForm::class => CreditCardFormFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
],
```

This then works:

```
$sm   = $this->getServiceLocator();
$form = $sm->get( 'FormElementManager' )->get( CreditCardForm::class );
$form->get( 'card-holder-name' )->setValue( 'Peter Smith' );
$viewModel->setVariable( 'form', $form );
```

When you render that form in your template (highly recommend Twig and the neilime TWBS package on Github) it'll be populated as expected.  I hope this post helps you!

Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your replies. Current solution is to set a default value in the related Entity:

```
     /**
      * Product
      *
      * @ORM\Table(name="products")
      * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\Entities\ProductRepository")
      */
      class Product
      {

       const DEFAULT_AMOUNT = 1;

       public function __construct()
       {
          $this->setAmount($this->getDefaultAmount());
       }
```

}

This works, I do like the solution given above and will definitely look into Twig.